unable to hide next.js built-in toast error message
Next.js toast error not getting hide.
i am working on next.js first time.i am facing an issue due to which i am getting error message in a toast at bottom left corner. i want to hide that toast. i inspect the element and found the following code:
<div data-nextjs-toast="true" class="nextjs-toast-errors-parent">
   <div data-nextjs-toast-wrapper="true">
      <div class="nextjs-toast-errors">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
            <line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"></line>
            <line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12.01" y2="16"></line>
         </svg>
         <span>5 errors</span>
         <button data-nextjs-toast-errors-hide-button="true" class="nextjs-toast-errors-hide-button" type="button" aria-label="Hide Errors">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
               <path d="M18 6L6 18" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
               <path d="M6 6L18 18" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


here is the css details corresponding to the above code's
.nextjs-toast-errors-parent {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

if i try to add
display:none;
in the above css , then it disappears.
so i come to my vs code and add the following code in my globals.css file
.nextjs-toast-errors-parent {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
    diplay:none;
}

but it does not work. i try to put the !important with display:none but that is also not working.
i found a something on the internet that is nextjs-portal

so i implement the following

nextjs-portal {
  display: none;
}

it hides all the errors , not even toast error but also the overlay errors.
how i can resolve this issue , i am unable to figure out why my css code is not working. is there any other way to implement this.

why do you want to hide it? in dev mode this toast helps you to debug errors

@VladVladov actually this issue is related to hydration errors. which i am unable to solve. so for now i want to hide this. can you tell me how i can do that

Better to concentrate on solving errors than hiding error info - the error will eventually go to production builds

@VladVladov that's the issue , the code is deployed to the server with build , but i still the error is  visible
